# Alignment of selectizeInput and numericInputs generated inside renderUI

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I have an app where the user will generate a bunch of `selectizeInput`s along with 3 `numericInput`s for every `selectizeInput`. The problem I am having is that the `selectizeInput` does not align well with the `numericInput`s and once you have about 10 rows, the alignment is completely gone.

I have thought of two ways of solving this problem:

1. create one `renderUI` function and include `fluidRow`s in a loop but some searching has led me to believe that isnt possible.
2. Height adjust the selectizeInput with using  `tags$style(type = "text/css", ".form-control.shiny-bound-input,  .selectize-input {height: 46px;}"),` but I dont want to adjust the `selectizeInput` height universally as the app has selectizeInputs elsewhere.
   I can't really hardcode the input name with `tags$style(type = "text/css", "#some_id.form-control.shiny-bound-input {height: 46px;}")` since the names are dynamically generated by the user.

Will one of these two options work? If not is there a third option?

I have made a demo version of the problem below.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 3, br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(), h6("something else is here")),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Problem tab",
                 br(),
                 numericInput("inputs_num","Enter Number of Channels to Calibrate", min = 1, value = 10),
                 hr(),
                 br(),
                 fluidRow(
                   column(width= 3,uiOutput("colname")),
                   column(width =3, uiOutput("initial_numeric")),
                   column(width =3, uiOutput("min_numeric")),
                   column(width =3, uiOutput("max_numeric"))
                 ),
                 hr()
                 )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, server){
  
  output$colname <- renderUI({
    req(input$inputs_num)
    columns <- colnames(mtcars)
    tags <- tagList()
    for(i in 1:input$inputs_num){
      tags[[i]] = selectizeInput(paste0("colname_",i), paste0("Column ",i), choices = columns, selected = NULL,
                                 options = list(
                                   placeholder = "Enter Column Name",
                                   onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                                 ))
    }
    tags
  })
  
  
  output$initial_numeric <- renderUI({
    req(input$inputs_num)
    tags <- tagList()
    for (i in 1:input$inputs_num){
      tags[[i]] <- numericInput(paste0("initial_",i), paste("Initial",i), min = 0,value = 1)
    }
    tags
  })
  
  output$min_numeric <- renderUI({
      req(input$inputs_num)
    tags <- tagList()
    for (i in 1:input$inputs_num){
      tags[[i]] <- numericInput(paste0("min_",i), paste("Min",i), min = 0,value = 1)
    }
    tags
  })
  
  output$max_numeric <- renderUI({
    req(input$inputs_num)
    tags <- tagList()
    for (i in 1:input$inputs_num){
      tags[[i]] <- numericInput(paste0("max_",i), paste("Max",i), min = 0,value = 1)
    }
    tags
  })
 

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Safari everything was aligned fine, and only in Firefox it became visible. I tried wrapping everything in one loop and it seems to work fine, even in Firefox.

So the approach below should correspond to solution 1. Since solution 2 (changing the css of the input universally) is not an option, another approach would be to define custom inputs by wrapping the original inputs  in a tag and adding an additional class which can then be targeted in css. But I think that this not necessary, since the approach below works.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 3, br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(), h6("something else is here")),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Problem tab",
                 br(),
                 numericInput("inputs_num","Enter Number of Channels to Calibrate", min = 1, value = 10),
                 hr(),
                 br(),
                 uiOutput("all"),
                 hr()
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, server){

  output$all <- renderUI({
    req(input$inputs_num)
    columns <- colnames(mtcars)
    tags <- tagList()
    for(i in 1:input$inputs_num){
      tags[[i]] <- fluidRow(
        column(width= 3,
          selectizeInput(paste0("colname_",i), paste0("Column ",i), choices = columns, selected = NULL,
                       options = list(
                         placeholder = "Enter Column Name",
                         onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                       ))),
        column(width= 3,
          numericInput(paste0("initial_",i), paste("Initial",i), min = 0,value = 1)),
        column(width= 3,
          numericInput(paste0("min_",i), paste("Min",i), min = 0,value = 1)),
        column(width= 3,
          numericInput(paste0("max_",i), paste("Max",i), min = 0,value = 1))
      )
    }
    tags
  })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks I was overcomplicating this with trying to generate a fluidRow for every row :)